# Redux Form - Return current input value as string onChange

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to show a 'tick' next to my input when it contains at least 1 character to show a required field as being valid. The issue I have is that currently when I `console.log(textEntered)` each time the field changes I receive an object containing all the typed letters instead of a complete string. If I typed in 'hello' for example the log looks this (ignore the undefined):

[image]

Here is my Redux Field Component:

```
handleInput = (textEntered) => {
  console.log(textEntered);
  this.setState({ textEntered }, () => {
    if (this.state.textEntered.length) {
      this.setState({ completed: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ completed: false });
    }
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <Field
      name={this.props.placeholderText}
      component={TextInput}
      onChange={this.handleInput}
    />
  );
}

const TextInput = (field) => {
  return (
    <div className="drill-creation-input">
      <input
        {...field.input}
        type="input"
        onChange={e => field.input.onChange(e.target.value)}
      />

      <label htmlFor={field.input.name}>
        <span>{field.input.name}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OnChange handler has the following signature (see [docs](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/Field.md/))

```
onChange : (event, newValue, previousValue)
```

So to read the complete value, just define your `handleInput` like:

```
handleInput = (evnt, textEntered) => {
  console.log(textEntered);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it. Should be the accepted answer